# Unable to stream to nginx deployed on compute engine from OBS

Tags: nginx, video-streaming, rtmp

I have been trying to setup nginx with rtmp module on google compute engine by creating a Debian vm. I have successfully installed and configured nginx to use rtmp module. I am able to get to the welcome message in the browser when I use http://
However, when I trying to test my stream using OBS I get the following message:

```
Failed to connect to server. 
Connection timed out. Make sure you've configured a valid streaming service and no firewall is blocking the connection.
```

I think OBS is timing out because its not able to reach the rtmp module. I am wondering if I need to tweak any settings in compute engine so that it allows rtmp connections. I tried looking into firewall setting but it didn't look like anything related to rtmp is blocked. I have also tried deleting the vms and re-doing everything a few times but every time I end up with the same error. Does anyone know of a way to test what's actually going on and why OBS might not be able to connect to nginx? 
My initial thoughts were that since rtmp module is running on the vm and is configured to `listen 1935;` so it might just be listening on internal ip. However if I change the `nginx.conf` to reflect something like `listen <external-ip>:1935` it gives me `nginx: [emerg] bind() to <external-ip>:1935 failed (99: Cannot assign requested address)` Any thoughts on the matter would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

So after some more poking around the internet I found that VMs by default don't allow access to all ports. That is the firewall in general blocks ports unless specified. So I just opened the TCP port at 1935 in the firewall settings and that seemed to do the trick.